# Unable to compare two columns using like operator in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with clean city names (table1) and another one with unclean city names data (table2).

Sample data:
Table1 City: Bhopal
Table2 City: Shivaji nagar, Bhopal

I am trying to use the like operator to compare table1.city with table2.city and get table1.city as an output column.

I tried the below query.

`select * from table2, table1 where table1.city_name like '%'+table2.city_name+'%'`

I am getting an error saying 'Numeric value '%' is not recognized'

Comment: Is there any special reason of using operator LIKE instead of = ?

Comment: @learning Yes, the texts are not exactly same so I cannot use =.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake uses the ANSI operator `||` for string concatenation, not `+`.  Also, you need to phrase that the second city is like/contains the first, not the other way around.

```sql
SELECT t1.city_name
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t2.city_name LIKE '%' || t1.city_name || '%'
);
```